# Solution for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am stuck in getting the solution for the following non-linear differential equation:
\begin{equation*}
x^2 + B\frac{dx}{dt} = A\sin(wt)
\end{equation*}
Is there any method to solve this kind of equation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: This equation is reduced to form u′′=Asin(wt)u . Does it have any known solution . To be more elaborate this is the equation which represents the dynamics in an  electrical engineering problem .

Answer (score 1):

The general solution cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions. A closed form (see below) involves the Mathieu's functions : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuFunction.html

If those special functions are not implemented on your mathematical software, use numerical methods for solving the ODEs. And even if the Mathieu functions are avalaible, it is generally simpler to use numerical methods in pratice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x= Q \frac{u'}{u}$

$$Q^2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}+BQ'\frac{u'}{u}+BQ\frac{u''}{u}-BQ\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=A\sin (wt)$$

Pick $Q$ such that

$$Q^2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}-BQ\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=0$$

We get $Q=B$, $Q'=0$. Multiply everything by u:

$B^2u''=A \sin (wt) u$

Which, I'm afraid, has no solution in terms of known functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there any approximation method in which an answer is available in terms of known functions??

Comment: @SriRam Where is this equation from?

Comment: One example solution (in the middle interval, orange and blue coincides) https://i.imgur.com/0gHWAmG.png I would imagine it'd be very difficult to approximate.

Comment: @grdgfdr this is an analog circuit design problem which I got during  studying harmonic distortion in current mirrors . But I am imagining how would the electrical simulators find solution to such differential equations. Here A sin(wt) is input and x(t) is output . I am getting harmonics in simulation results but not able to quantify those results mathematically.

Comment: All simulations use numerical methods.